# Data validation for each cell to check whether the value is available or not using EPplus

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, epplus

I am using Epplus for uploading file.I have two sheet in .xlsx format.I want to ensure that each and every cell has value.For example in my excel i have dropdown box.If a user have details in first sheet and second sheet is empty.But this empty sheet have only one value which is added in sheet by mistake by use of this dropdown.So at this stage it will show object null reference error when it goes in to this loop

```
    for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
     {

         if (int.TryParse(s.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString(), out n) && int.TryParse(s.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString(), out n))
        {
          Pss.Pbr = Convert.ToInt32(s.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value);
          Pss.Amount = Convert.ToInt32(s.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value);
         Ps.Add(Pss);

        }
}
```

how to validate that all columns and row have values

Comment: You're trying to add user input validation https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/epplus/8739/user-input-validation#t=201706081129231042737 or you're trying to check in your code that the cell has value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the loop, check if the cell is not null and is not empty, like this:

```
bool allRangeHasValue=true;
for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
{
    for(int col =1;col<=s.Dimension.End.Column;col++)
    {

      if(String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Cells[rowIterator, col]?.Value?.ToString())
      {
          allRangeHasValue=false;
          break;
      }
    }
    if(!allRangeHasValue)
    {
      break;
    }
}
```

Edit:
Based on your comment, you could do something like:
Edit2: Since you're using TryParse, you don't need to parse again, TryParse returns the value in the out variable.

```
for (int rowIterator = 2; rowIterator <= noOfRow; rowIterator++)
 {
     int n1;
     int n2;
     if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Cells[rowIterator, 1]?.Value?.ToString()) &&
         !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(s.Cells[rowIterator, 2]?.Value?.ToString()) &&
         int.TryParse(s.Cells[rowIterator, 1].Value.ToString(), out n1) && 
         int.TryParse(s.Cells[rowIterator, 2].Value.ToString(), out n2))
    {
      Pss.Pbr = n1;
      Pss.Amount = n2;
      Ps.Add(Pss);

    }
}
```